# Java: How do I initialize an array with objects of a class at the time of object creation?

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements

I'm working on a code and I want to return the ranking board of the teams in the championship.

I want to make an `ArrayList` that contain the objects of a class name `Team`, so I can return the whole ranking board with  all the teams .

I want it done at the time of object creation and in this respect I have the following code that is not working:

```
// the constructor
public Team(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        teams.add(this);
    }

public List<Team<T>> teams = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have also tried to initialised teams inside a method in which I add the players:

```
public boolean addMembers(T player) {
        if (members.contains(player)) {
            System.out.println("Player already in the list");
            return false;
        } else {
            members.add(player);
            teams.add(this);
            System.out.println(player.getName() + " has been picked for team " + this.name);
            returnClassament();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain ["is not working"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). Anyway you probably may pass list of teams as constructor parameter instead of making it a field in Team class.

Comment: Wait, do you have a list of teams inside of each team? Like, does a team consist of many different teams? What is the logic behind that?

Comment: @Amongalen I can create different type of teams: basketball, fotbal etc. Inside of each team I add the team players

Comment: @Pshemo In order to create a method to display the ranking board I want to make an array of teams. When I print the array it is empty, so I think is a mistake somewhere. But is good to know how we can do this at time of object creation

Comment: Your question, as well as sample code, doesn't help in understanding your problem completely. 1) Where is the ArrayList object defined 2) Where is `addMembers` defined? 3) What issue you are facing. Is is that you are getting expecting or empty array?

Comment: I think you should comment line by line and explain what exactly each statement is supposed to do. This will help you.

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh, I whant to creeate  a method that return the ranking of each team sorted. For me to do this i need acces to all my teams (objects of Team class). All the code is in Team class.

Comment: @jschnasse it will be better to post the whole code ?

Comment: Having a list of all teams in each team makes no sense whatsoever. You should create a class `Championship` or something like that and have all the teams participating in there. You even said it yourself "I want to return the ranking board of the **teams in the championship**" - not teams in teams but teams in championship.

Comment: Please use [edit] option to add that problem description into the question. Anyway perhaps acceptable solution for you would be to create additional class like TeamsBoard and which would have a list of its own teams (baseball, volleyball, ..) and pass instance of that board while creating Team (something like `Team(String name, TeamsBoard teams){this.name = name; teams.addTeam(this);}`

Comment: Please do not post all code. You should post relevant parts together with error message and your question.

Comment: Try making the declaration as static and see if it helps `public static List<Team> teams = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Just create a class name `Team` but don't put the list in the Team, List<Team> should put outside the class definition, maybe in the main() method, and init all the teams one by one, then add them into the List.

Comment: @Pshemo yes it can be a better solution. tks!

Comment: @AshishkumarSingh If I make static I lose the generic tye

Comment: @Amongalen You are right. I was thinking that I can call the ranks (for all teams) with a method that can be called with an indtance of Team class

Answer (score 1):

this way may be helpful if I did not misunderstand you

```
     public Team(String name, List<Team> list) {
        this.name = name;
        if(list != null) list.add(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Team{
//we create private variables here because only the constructor is accessing them
private String name;
private int score;
  
  //create a static ArrayList that holds type of class Team here so all objects refer to one and it is not copied over to each object (as per i've learned because static is confusing)
  public static ArrayList<Team> teams=new ArrayList<Team>(); 

  
  public Team(String name,int score){
    this.name=name;
    this.score=score;
    //tell the program that the instance variable has the same value as the parameter
    teams.add(this);
    //adding the object to the ArrayList
  }

//This is not necessary; it just prints the values of each object in the ArrayList
public void printTeamStats(){
  System.out.println(name+" "+score);
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The AddPlayer method of the Championship class can be used to add a player to the system

```
Void addPlayer (String surname, Strong country, integer age, String position) {
```